# Unable to use an index on the selected item of a ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have this:

```
string curr = "";
if (emails.SelectedItem != null)
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
  {
    curr = (emails.SelectedItem.ToString()[i] + "." + 
            emails.SelectedItem.ToString()[i + 1]);
    clone.Items.Add(curr);
  }
}
```

However, whenever I run it, it gives me the "index was out of bounds of the array" error.

Why? What's the fix?

Also, how do I make it add the rest of the string (not just i + 1) to clone?

EXPLANATION OF CODE:

I'm trying to insert a period (.) after one letter of the word, then add it to clone. After that, I want to add a period after the SECOND letter, add to clone, period after third letter, add, etc...

However, I don't want to have it be `t.h.i.s.i.s.t.h.e.n.a.m.e`, I want it to just have one period at a time.

It should look like:

> a.ntimatter
>   an.timatter
>   ant.imatter
>   anti.matter
>   etc...

Comment: Why have you hardcoded 19? Where does that magic number come from?

Comment: And what are you trying to do? Adding a point (`.`) after each char of an email address?

Comment: That's the length of the portion of the string I need to modify is

Comment: @AndreCalil No, just after the first letter, then make another item in the listbox with the period one further, etc...

Comment: The code is confusing.  We probably need an explanation of what the situation is, and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @LarsTech Added an explanation to the question.

Comment: @chipperyman573 I'm sorry, but I still don't understand.

Comment: the last line is again confusing, if it shouldn't be `t.h.i.s.i.s.t.h.e.n.a.m.e` , what it should be ?

Comment: Do you want to loop selected items, OR only items?

Comment: @habib it should be first t.hisisthename, then th.isisthename, then thi.sisthename, etc...

Comment: @chipperyman573, ok that is good now, you may add it to your question

Comment: I updated your question with hopefully the correct example of what you are attempting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (emails.SelectedItem != null)
{
    var item = emails.SelectedItem.ToString();
    for (int i = 1; i < item.Length; i++)
    {
         clone.Items.Add(item.Insert(i, "."));
    }
}
```

Comment: `<=` will give you array out of bound exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (emails.SelectedItem != null) {
    string text = emails.SelectedItem.ToString();
    for (int i = 1; i < text.Length; i++) {
        string textWithPeriod = text.Substring(0, i) + "." + text.Substring(i);
        clone.Items.Add(textWithPeriod); 
    }
}
```